# Cannot resolve Servlet in idea

Tags: servlets, web, intellij-idea, java-web-start

In idea JavaWeb Project, we wrote a project file and push to github (run correctly), but when I download it and run it, it has some problem.

In web.xml file,i see below problem:

[image]

> Servlet should have a mapping-name

---

> Cannot resolve Servlet

---

I find some similar problems in stackoverflow, but my idea is latest version, and my project structure is set up:

[image]

So why web.xml cannot resolve my servelt?

Comment: Make sure servlet is under the source root. Provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if it still doesn't work.